# Why is sqrt(6) used to calculate epsilon for random initialisation of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, random-generation

In the [week 5 lecture notes](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/resources/EcbzQ) for [Andrew Ng's Coursera Machine Learning Class](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic_-Wp_4zVAhXFQpQKHXEUAL4QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coursera.org%2Flearn%2Fmachine-learning&usg=AFQjCNFi71uTd6io7et3THdcBVsE4H3QRg), the following formula is given for calculating the value of $\epsilon$ used to initialise $\Theta$ with random values:

[image: Forumla for calculating epsilon-init for random initialisation]

In the [exercise](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/programming/AiHgN/neural-network-learning), further clarification is given:

> One effective strategy for choosing $\epsilon_{init}$
>   is to base it on the number of units in the
>   network. A good choice of  $\epsilon_{init}$ is $\epsilon_{init} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{L_{in} - L_{out}}}$, where $L_{in}
> = s_l$ and $L_{out} = s_{l+1}$ are
>   the number of units in the layers adjacent to $\Theta^{(l)}$.

Why is the constant $\sqrt 6$ used here? Why not $\sqrt 5$, $\sqrt 7$ or $\sqrt {6.1}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is Xavier *normalized initialization* (implemented in several deep learning frameworks eg Keras, Cafe, ...)
 from [Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) by Xavier Glorot & Yoshua Bengio.

See equations 12, 15 and 16 in the paper linked: they aim to satisfy equation 12: 
$$\text{Var}[W_i] = \frac{2}{n_i + n_{i+1}}$$

and the variance of a uniform RV in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is $\epsilon^2/3$ (mean is zero, pdf = $1/(2\epsilon)$ so variance $=\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}x^2 \frac{1}{2\epsilon}dx$

Comment: Hmm, so why use $\sqrt 6$ instead of $2$?

Comment: Plug epsilon into the formula for variance of uniform random variable in +/-x and what do you get?

Comment: Doh! I now see in formulae (16) that $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ is used. Where do you get $x^2 / 3$ from though?

Comment: added explanation for variance of uniform RV...